# Ruby notation conventions

Tags: ruby, annotations

When writing about ruby code we use:

- `Dog` to represent the dog class
- `#bark` to represent an instance method
- `.new` or `::new` to represent a class method

What's the convention for representing an instance of a class? `dog` would blend right in with the surrounding regular text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds about right. In Smalltalk, it is customary to use `anArray`, `aString` or `aDog` (even as parameter names in method declarations), which would translate to `an_array`, `a_string` or `a_dog`. However, that's not customary, and might look strange to an experienced Rubyist, who would expect to see `ary`, `str` and `dog`.

Note also that in general, the dot is *only* used in code *examples* for actual method *calls*. When talking *about* the method, *always* use `#` and `::` for instance methods and singleton methods.

Comment: Why are singleton methods associated with `::`? (I know it's possible to use `::` in Ruby code, but I don't know why Matz chose `::`).